# What are the differences between Logistic Function and Sigmoid Function?

Tags: logistic

$$
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}
\end{equation}
$$

Fig 1. ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1DX2.png)) [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

$$
\begin{equation}
S(x)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}
\end{equation}
$$

Fig 2. ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeba6.png)) [Sigmoid Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

What are the differences between Logistic Function and Sigmoid Function? Is the logistic function a generalized kind of sigmoid function where you could have a higher maximum value?

Comment: $S$ is an increasing function in $t$, $f$ is increasing for values of $x \leq x_0$, decreasing for values of $x \geq x_0$

Comment: @mic I don't think that's right. If $t>0$, $S$ (the OP's "sigmoid function") is monotonically increasing. If $k>0$, (the OP's logistic function) $f$ is monotonically increasing. Both functions are monotonically increasing or decreasing, none of them increase for some values of $x$ and decrease for other values of $x$. The [**derivative**](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/logisic-sigmoid-derivative.html) increases then decreases, as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+exp-x%2F%7B1+%2B+exp-x%7D%5E2%2C+with+-10+%3C+x+%3C+10), is that what you meant by $f$?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the sigmoid function is a special case of the Logistic function when $L=1$, $k=1$, $x_0 =0$.

If you [play around with the parameters (Wolfram Alpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%2F%7B1%2Bexp%7B-2%7Bx-0%7D%7D%7D,+with+-10+%3C+x+%3C+10), you will see that

- $L$ controls the maximum value the function can take. $e^{-k(x-x_0)}$ is always greater or equal than 0, so the maximum point is achieved when $e^{-k(x-x_0)}$ is 0 so the logistic function has value $L/1$.
- $x_0$ controls where on the $x$ axis the growth is centered, because if you put $x_0$ in the function, $x_0 - x_0$ cancel out and $e^0 = 1$, so you end up with $f(x_0) = L/2$, the midpoint of the growth.
- $k$ controls how steep the growth from the minimum to the maximum value is.

Answer (score 2):

The logistic function is:
$$
f(x) = \frac{K}{1+Ce^{-rx}}
$$
where $C$ is the constant from integration, $r$ is the proportionality constant, and $K$ is the threshold limit.

Assuming the limits are between $0$ and $1$, we get $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ which is the sigmoid function.

Comment: what is $C$ -- I don't see it in the OP's question. What does "constant from integration" mean? Do you have an example to cite, so we can learn more?

Comment: Trying to answer my question, [this resource](https://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/10040800/user_upload/time_series/the_book/2012-August-01-times.pdf), ("A First Course on Time Series Analysis") says: "the function $\frac{β3}{1 + β2 exp(−β1t)}$ with $β1, β2, β3 ∈ \!R $ **is the widely used logistic function** Its $β2$ is same as your $C$. [This video is also consistent with your definition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hois2F0bSxU&t=15s). But I'm still trying to understand the significance of $C$, aka $β2$, and why Wikipedia doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say in opposite way to the answer "the sigmoid function is a special case of the Logistic function" into "The Logisitic function is a special case of the sigmoid function". All S shape curved monotonically increasing fuction being confined a and b are sigmoid functions.

Comment: That is also how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) describes the sigmoid functions.

Comment: Interesting - I upvoted you -- Wikipedia does say that sigmoid functions is a general category of any "S-shaped curve", and gives [logistic function as just one example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples). However, Wikipedia labels the "logistic function" example with the definition $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ , which is what the OP calls the "sigmoid function". There are more parameters in what the OP calls the "logistic function". So you're right, but I also think the accepted answer is right in addressing the OP's definitions.